# R regex reversing string with parentheses

Tags: regex, r

Suppose you want to reverse a string that parts sectioned off by parentheses and parts that aren't. What would be the best possible regex method to approach this? Here is a link to my last question addressing a similar issue [R regex - splitting between parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079262/r-regex-splitting-between-parentheses)

```
x <- "(A|C|T)AG(C|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)GCC(C|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G)"

# Desired output
rev_x
"(A|C|G)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)CCG(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)GA(A|C|T)"
```

Comment: @akrun so the question is about how to reverse a vector? then close as a duplicate

Comment: @akrun here ya go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933441/how-to-reverse-order-a-vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also try `stri_extract_all` from `library(stringi)` to extract the characters along with the parentheses as a group (`\\([^)]+\\)`) or (`|`) any other character (`.`) in a `list` with a single list element, which can we extract with `[[1]]`, then reverse the `vector` (`rev`) and `paste` it with `collapse=''`

```
library(stringi)
paste(rev(stri_extract_all(x, regex='\\([^)]+\\)|.')[[1]]), collapse='')
#[1] "(A|C|G)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)CCG(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(A|C|G|T)(C|T)GA(A|C|T)"
```